# I have never heard (about/of) anyone doing that?

Tags: prepositions

As the title suggests: **I have never heard (about/of) anyone doing that?**

Which is correct: *of* or *about*?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of pigs flying.
I have never heard about a woman having three husbands.

"Never heard of" implies you think it is impossible. "Never heard about" may simply mean that you have led a quiet life, and not had much experience of the world.